# Why is created subdomain not working in my xampp local server?

Tags: server, xampp, localhost

I am running a XAMPP local server on my Parrot OS Virtual Machine. I have attempted to create subdomains to my localhost My plan is to create the following subdomains:
`admin.localhost`
`help.localhost`

To achieve this goal, I have made the following changes:

1. I have edited my `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf` file and uncommented the line `Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
2. I have edited my `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file and added the following lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/dashboard"
    ServerName localhost
    
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/dashboard">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/dvwa"
    ServerName admin.localhost
    
    
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/dvwa">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/dvwa"
    ServerName help.localhost
    
    
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/dvwa">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/xvwa"
    ServerName localhost
    
    
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/xvwa">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

3. I edited my `/etc/hosts` file and added the following lines:
   `127.0.0.1 admin.localhost 127.0.0.1 help.localhost`
4. Then I restarted XAMPP by running the following command:
   `/opt/lampp/lampp start`

But when I go to the browser and type `admin.localhost` or `help.localhost`, it takes me to the default page for `localhost`.